# How to remotely execute a bash script in pycharm?

Tags: bash, pycharm

I own the licensed version of Pycharm. I have installed `BashSupport plugin` as well.

However, I am not sure what steps are required to remotely test and execute a bash script on RHEL server.

I am able to configure a remote interpreter but the interpreter path is `/usr/bin/python`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my logic you need to change interpreter path to /bin/bash instead of /usr/bin/python or i don't understand what you are trying to do..

Answer (score 0):

I've met the save problem today. 
If I use the default pycharm bash configuration, I'll get the following error:

```
C:\windows\system32\bash.exe C:/git/NewProject/run.sh  
/bin/bash: C:/git/NewProject/run.sh: No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 127
```

[image: error run remote bash]

So, I change the default **Windows Script path** to **Linux absolute Script path** as following:
[image]

Run successfully. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You gotta check the path on server, If there is alias set, You can check alias

```
$ which python
$ whence python (Some version)
$ ls -l `which python`
```